# Hover images not showing

Tags: html, css, hover

I have created a site with pictures, the idea is that when you hover over the image you see some info, when you click on it, you see the whole info.

This is the code I used:

```css
#SWAT {
  background: url("img/SWAT-01.png");
  width: 855px;
  height: 160px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#SWAT:hover {
  background: url("IMG/SWAT-02.png");
}

#SWAT:active {
  background: url("IMG/SWAT-03.png");
}

#Jennifer {
  background: url("img/Jennifer-1.png");
  width: 161px;
  height: 160px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}

#Jennifer:hover {
  background: url("IMG/Jennifer-2.png");
}

#Jennifer:active {
  background: url("IMG/Jennifer-3.png");
}

#Kosh {
  background: url("img/Kosh-1.png");
  width: 160px;
  height: 162px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}

#Kosh:hover {
  background: url("IMG/Kosh-2.png");
}

#Kosh:active {
  background: url("IMG/Kosh-3.png");
}

#VM {
  background: url("img/VM-1.png");
  width: 507px;
  height: 162px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}

#VM:hover {
  background: url("IMG/VM-2.png");
}

#VM:active {
  background: url("IMG/VM-3.png");
}

#MJ {
  background: url("img/MJ-1.png");
  width: 332px;
  height: 164px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}

#MJ:hover {
  background: url("IMG/MJ-2.png");
}

#MJ:active {
  background: url("IMG/MJ-3.png");
}

#Cheke {
  background: url("img/Cheke-1.png");
  width: 161px;
  height: 162px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}

#Cheke:hover {
  background: url("IMG/Cheke-2.png");
}

#Cheke:active {
  background: url("IMG/Cheke-3.png");
}

#LauraM {
  background: url("img/LauraM-1.png");
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}

#LauraM:hover {
  background: url("IMG/LauraM-2.png");
}

#LauraM:active {
  background: url("IMG/LauraM-3.png");
}

#Vilma {
  background: url("img/Vilma-1.png");
  width: 161px;
  height: 162px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}

#Vilma:hover {
  background: url("IMG/Vilma-2.png");
}

#Vilma:active {
  background: url("IMG/Vilma-3.png");
}

#AnaLu {
  background: url("img/AnaLu-1.png");
  width: 162px;
  height: 161px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}

#AnaLu:hover {
  background: url("IMG/AnaLu-2.png");
}

#AnaLu:active {
  background: url("IMG/AnaLu-3.png");
}

#Mario {
  background: url("img/Mario-1.png");
  width: 160px;
  height: 161px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}

#Mario:hover {
  background: url("IMG/Mario-2.png");
}

#Mario:active {
  background: url("IMG/Mario-3.png");
}

#Ansu {
  background: url("img/Ansu-1.png");
  width: 162px;
  height: 161px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}

#Ansu:hover {
  background: url("IMG/Ansu-2.png");
}

#Ansu:active {
  background: url("IMG/Ansu-3.png");
}

#mas {
  width: 334px;
  height: 161px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="SWAT"></div><br>
<div id="Jennifer"></div>
<div id="Kosh"></div>
<div id="VM"></div><br>
<div id="MJ"></div>
<div id="Cheke"></div>
<div id="LauraM"></div>
<div id="Vilma"></div><br>
<div id="AnaLu"></div>
<div id="Mario"></div>
<div id="Ansu"></div>
<div id="mas">
  <a class='default-link' href="http:google.com"><img src="IMG/mas-2.png"></a>
</div><br>
<br>
```

I'm so sorry it's so long but I don't know where I went wrong. Anyways I did this on Brackets, and while working on it it looked fine in Chrome and Safari. however, once I uploaded it into my site and went live, the default images disappeared! I can see the hover images if I hover over them, and when I click on them the active image shows as well, but the defaults don't show.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Do you see any errors in your console?

Comment: I don't think so?? At least I don't see anything in Brackets (which I assume is the console? I'm so sorry I'm really just a beginner) and when I run the html file in Chrome everything loads correctly,, it's when I load the files on the server that the images don't show (???)

Comment: Actually, your code works (I tried with online images). So I think that probably your are setting the wrong path/directory for the images... To see console errors, open the DevTools of your browser when running your page pressing `F12`. Check the directories and if possible show us the folders/directories structures

Comment: Hi, check it the path of your images, perphaps is a misstype route.

Comment: @CalvinNunes thank you! I found the console errors and yes, all of my default images seem to have errors. However when I go to the IMG folder, all the images are there ??? other images that are working say in the type "png", but these images that have errors say "text/html". Could this be because I used background: url instead of background-image? (I did it this way because it's the way I saw it online)

Comment: usually using `background` or `background-image` won't be a problem... in devTools, network tab, look for the images and see if the path is exactly the same  you expect, if possible, paste here in the question an image of the errors of your console.log and/or network tab

Comment: @CalvinNunes when looking for the paths I noticed that all the images that weren't appearing were in lowercase -_- I fixed it and that seemed to be the end of it! Now I have just noticed that the effect doesn't show on mobile :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rare, but it could be that the environment/server you are working on is case-sensitive. 
You have uppercase img folder on some (**IMG**/Ansu-1.png) and lowercase on others (**img**/Ansu-1.png).

Comment: I can't believe it! It was the case sensitive thing. Coding is so finnicky in these things hahahaha but I've learned my lesson! thank you!